# Method to calculate prime numbers - [JAVA]

Tags: java

I need to build a method that calculates a prime number for my homework. I implemented the algorithm proposed by my professor but it's not working.

Eclipse gives the message: `The local variable prime may not have been initialized` and does not compile.

Can someone help me?

```
public static boolean itsPrime(int nbTest){

    boolean prime;

    if (nbTest <= 1){
         prime = false;
    } else if (nbTest == 2){       // Two is the only even number that is prime
        prime = true;
    } else if ((nbTest != 2) && (nbTest % 2 == 0)){    // If it's even and different than two it is not prime
        prime = false;
    } else {
        for(int i = 3; i <= Math.sqrt(nbTest); i = i+2){ 
            if (nbTest % i == 0){
                prime = false;
            } else {
                prime = true;
            }
        }   
    }

    return prime;
}
```

Comment: do what it says then :P `boolean prime = false;` Also you don't need to make this variable and return it. You can just simply say `return false;` or `return true;`

Answer (score 2):

Just initialise it when you declare the variable. EG

```
boolean prime = false;
```

Answer (score 1):

You did not initialize the variable `prime` in your code. By just looking at it, you saw that every branch of the if statement assigns a value to `prime`. However, there is one exceptional case, what if the `for` loop doesn't get executed? Then the value of `prime` is unknown! So that's why the error appears.

I guess you want to return `false` if the loop doesn't get executed so just initialize `prime` with `false` when you declare it:

```
boolean prime = false;
```

To make your code better, instead of just assigning values to `prime`, you can just return! Let me show you the full code:

```
public static boolean itsPrime(int nbTest){

    boolean prime = false;

    if (nbTest <= 1){
         return false;
    } else if (nbTest == 2){       // Two is the only even number that is prime
        return false;
    } else if ((nbTest != 2) && (nbTest % 2 == 0)){    // If it's even and different than two it is not prime
        return false;
    } else {
        for(int i = 3; i <= Math.sqrt(nbTest); i = i+2){ 
            if (nbTest % i == 0){
                prime = false;
            } else {
                prime = true;
            }
        }   
    }

    return prime;
}
```